# Results of custom top K accuracy differ from Keras top_k_categorical_accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, keras, multilabel-classification, metric

I am using my own top K accuracy metric for multi label classification:

```
def top_K_acc(y_true, y_pred, k):
    assert y_true.shape == y_pred.shape
    top_k_indx = np.argsort(y_pred, axis=1)[:,::-1][:,:k]
    n_guessed = 0
    for i in range(len(y_true)):
        if np.any(y_true[i,top_k_indx[i]]):
            n_guessed += 1
    print(n_guessed / len(y_true))
```

but it's always shows higher accuracy than `top_k_categorical_accuracy` from Keras. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried comparing the implementations?

Comment: @nemo I didn't found exact implementation in TF backend.

Comment: See https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/4fa7e5d454dd4f3f33f1d756a2a8659f2e789141/keras/metrics.py#L19